# Fazer o Wordpress direcionar um acesso à um arquivo PHP no tema

Tags: php, wordpress

Tenho a seguinte necessidade:

Tenho algumas páginas chamadas de "Diagnósticos" no meu site em Wordpress. Porém, os recursos padrões do WP não permitem fazer o que desejo. Preciso fazer alguns cálculos nestes diagnósticos, e consigo fazê-los fora do WP, com PHP comum mesmo.

Porém, como posso fazer para o WP direcionar, por exemplo, a página "/diagnosticos/diagnostico-de-processos" para o /wp-content/themes/meutema/diagnostico-de-processos.php"?

Comment: `<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() ?>/diagnostico-de-processos.php`

Comment: @ValdeirPsr esse trecho deve ser inserido aonde? Até onde sei, esse get_template_directory_uri apenas me traz o caminho até o tema. Não é isso que preciso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É só você criar um *page template* com o arquivo "diagnostico-de-processos.php". Você só precisa colocar o seguinte comentário no início do arquivo:

```
/**
 * Template name: Página de Diagnósticos
 */
```

No painel do **wordpress** você edita a página "/diagnosticos/diagnostico-de-processos" e seleciona o **template**: Página de Diagnósticos.
Assim o *wordpress* vai entender que você vai utilizar o arquivo "diagnostico-de-processos.php" para renderizar a página desejada.

Comment: PERFEITO! Muito obrigado, Kayo!